# 'Call to undefined function' - Trying to call function from an included file

Tags: php, wordpress, function, include, undefined

So I have two files, 'header.php' and 'pluginfile.php'

The function that I want to call resides in 'pluginfile.php' and is:

```
public function getNonSubscriptionAmount() {
    $total = 0;
    foreach($this->_items as $item) {
      if(!$item->isSubscription()) {
        $total += $item->getProductPrice() * $item->getQuantity();
      }
      else {
        // item is subscription
        $basePrice = $item->getBaseProductPrice();
        Cart66Common::log('[' . basename(__FILE__) . ' - line ' . __LINE__ . "] Item is a subscription with base price $basePrice");
        $total += $basePrice;
      }
    }
    return $total;
  }
```

So in 'header.php' I have:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/folder/PluginFile.php");
print getNonSubscriptionAmount();
?>
```

This gives the following error when any page is loaded:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function getnonsubscriptionamount() in
>   /home/username/domain.com/wp-content/themes/theme/header.php on
>   line 72

I've spent a couple of hours now trying to figure this out alone and am getting nowhere! Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You might try changing your include_once to a require_once which can make sure the file is being properly included in case there is something going on with the pathing.

Comment: `public function ...` This tells me it's defined as a class method, but you're calling it as though it's a standalone function.

Comment: good catch @Wiseguy, that would definitely cause problems.

Comment: SidewaysGravity - when changing to require the same message is displayed so I guess it's being included okay.

@Wiseguy That could totally be it...I'm not used to calling functions! May I ask how I should be doing it?

Comment: You need to instantiate an object of that class and call it from the object. For example, `$obj = new SomeClass; print $obj->getNonSubscriptionAmount();` More info about class methods in [the docs here](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: Really sorry @Wiseguy, could you put that into the context of my code? I am being stupid but can't figure what to put where (I don't usually mess with code!) Thanks

Comment: Well, not knowing what the plugin does, I don't know if it will work to just call that at the very beginning of your script. (Will all the necessary data be there?) But we can try. What's the name of the class that method is in (will look like `class Something {`). Use that "Something" name in place of "SomeClass" in my last comment.

Comment: @WiseGuy Thanks! It prints '0', tried it with a few of the functions within the class (it's a shopping cart plugin, i am trying to return the value of the cart, but i have tried it with the amount of items in the cart too. Both keep returning 0...might have to try something else!). Ahh I wish the plugin developer made this easier! Thanks very much - how can I mark this as answered when you helped me in the comments?

Comment: Glad you got it to work, but like I said, maybe the correct data won't be populated yet so you won't get useful values. :-/ I'd have to actually submit an answer for you to accept it. @SidewaysGravity said the same thing, so I'd suggest selecting his. I just added a bit of clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wiseguy looks like he had the right idea put in the comments.

You are declaring a method and not a function. Is the function the entirety of your plugin.php file or is there more? If it is everything, remove the public modifier and just declare

```
function getNonSubscriptionAmount() {
  // code here
}
```

But from the looks of the code it is part of a larger class. If thats the case then @Wiseguy comment is right on, you need to instantiate a new object of the class in plugin.php and then the desired method.

```
$obj = new PluginClass();
$obj->getNonSubscriptionAmount();
```

Comment: I'm still unsure of where I put this in my code, I just get errors!

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> The function that I want to call resides in 'plugin.php' and is:

And in your file you are including:

> So in 'header.php' I have:
>       include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/folder/PluginFile.php");
>       print getNonSubscriptionAmount();

You are not including 'plugin.php' which is were the function lives.

Header.php should include 'plugin.php', not 'PluginFile.php'.

Comment: apologies that was my mistake in writing the question!

Comment: Word, in that case my answer is of no help, hah.